# Calling python UDF from SQLite command line

Tags: python, sqlite, user-defined-functions

If I create an UDF in python with sqlite3.create_function, can I call that function from SQLite command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDFs are available only in the connection that created them.

You'd have to write your own command-line shell in Python.